# sudo apt-get upgrade gives an error: ibverbs-providers:i386 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, ubuntu-18.04, dpkg

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. When I try

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I am getting the following error:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ibverbs-providers:i386:
 ibverbs-providers:amd64 (17.1-1ubuntu0.2) breaks libcxgb3-1 and is installed.
  ibverbs-providers:i386 (17.1-1ubuntu0.2) provides libcxgb3-1.
 ibverbs-providers:amd64 (17.1-1ubuntu0.2) breaks libipathverbs1 and is installed.
  ibverbs-providers:i386 (17.1-1ubuntu0.2) provides libipathverbs1.
 ibverbs-providers:amd64 (17.1-1ubuntu0.2) breaks libmlx4-1 and is installed.
  ibverbs-providers:i386 (17.1-1ubuntu0.2) provides libmlx4-1.
 ibverbs-providers:amd64 (17.1-1ubuntu0.2) breaks libmlx5-1 and is installed.
  ibverbs-providers:i386 (17.1-1ubuntu0.2) provides libmlx5-1.
 ibverbs-providers:amd64 (17.1-1ubuntu0.2) breaks libmthca1 and is installed.
  ibverbs-providers:i386 (17.1-1ubuntu0.2) provides libmthca1.
 ibverbs-providers:amd64 (17.1-1ubuntu0.2) breaks libnes1 and is installed.
  ibverbs-providers:i386 (17.1-1ubuntu0.2) provides libnes1.

 dpkg: error processing package ibverbs-providers:i386 (--configure):
 dependencNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                                    y problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ibverbs-providers:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am unable to upgrade anything.

Comment: I solved the problem by removing the ibverbs-providers, then `apt autoremove` to remove the unused dependencies and then reinstalling it. If any other package depends on them, they will not be removed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `ibverbs-providers:i386` package has a new version which breaks several packages you have installed. The packages it seems to be breaking are the 64-bit versions of itself which is unfortunately extremely common and annoying.

As a temporary solution you can use the hold option of apt to not upgrade the package and not update it

`sudo apt-mark hold ibverbs-providers:i386`

You can find out more about hold from ubuntu's [Pinning guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto).

I would however recommended that you try and fix this dependency issue, try using a more modern/user friendly tool like `apt` or if that doesn't work `aptitude` (you will have to install aptitude). apt-get is a low level abstraction over dpkg and isnt really meant for use by humans (although many people including me have a habit of it since its been default on debian since forever). `apt` is a higher level manager which will do stuff like try and resolve dependencies and errors and aptitude is a full blown package manager with terminal GUI and many 'smart' features.

In my experience aptitude will solve this issue, apt may solve this issue.